# UnitTesting async code rxjava/rxkotlin fails with latch = 1 error

Tags: android, rx-java2, rx-kotlin

So I have the following test that keeps failing with the following error:

> java.lang.AssertionError: No values (latch = 1, values = 0, errors = 0, completions = 0)

```
val ocrProcessor = mockk<FirebaseFormProcessor>()
        val date = listOf(DateTextExtraction())

        every { ocrProcessor.scan(any(), any(), any()) } answers {
            thirdArg<OcrResultCallback>().invoke(date)
        }

        viewModel = FormViewModel(ocrProcessor)

        viewModel.addImage(bitmap)

        viewModel.ocrAlert
            .test()
            .assertValue {
                it == date
            }
            .addTo(disposeBag)
```

What this tries to test is the following:

```
override val ocrAlert: PublishSubject<List<TextExtractionInterface>> = PublishSubject.create()

override fun addImage(bitmap: Bitmap) {
    if (files.value.isEmpty())
        ocrProcessor.scan(bitmap, extract = textExtractionItems) { ocrResult ->
            ocrAlert.onNext(ocrResult)
        }
}
```

I am not quite sure what I am doing wrong here but I think it might have to do with threading problems.

edit:

I changed the code to this now:

```
        val toBeTested = viewModel.ocrAlert
            .subscribeOn(scheduler)
            .observeOn(scheduler)
            .test()

        viewModel.addImage(bitmap)

         toBeTested   
            .assertValue {
                it == date
            }
            .addTo(disposeBag)
```

Comment: `orcAlert` doesn't have any item the moment you test it thus the assertin fails. You have to call `test()`, signal `orcalert.onNext`, then call `TestObserver::assertValue` to see the item has arrived.

Comment: @akarnokd thanks for the response. So I have to break up the code? I already do addImage() before anything else which should trigger the onNext if I am correct.

Comment: `PublishSubject` doesn't store items so if there is nothing there to observe it, it will appear empty again.

Comment: how can I modify my test, in such a way, that it tests the correct way? An example would be great :) @akarnokd

Comment: Split the code as I suggested.

Comment: That didn't make any difference unfortunately. Or maybe I am doing it wrong. @akarnokd

Comment: Please post your entire new test.

Comment: @akarnokd I added how I think you explained it but not sure if that is correct :) Could you post the correct version of what you mean?

Comment: What is `scheduler` and where does it come from?

Comment: scheduler is a simple TestScheduler() which I do scheduler.triggerAction on as soon as the callback gets triggered.

Comment: Call `scheduler.triggerActions()` before and after the call `viewModel.addImage(bitmap)`.

Comment: that too didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: was thinking some throttle, buffer operator maybe could do the trick but @akarnokd wrote the library.

Comment: You are doing or have something wrong not shown. Please post an entire project demonstrating your issue as code snippets isn't enough to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @akarnokd I created a project demonstrating the issue here: https://github.com/reshadf/rxjava-tests

Comment: You haven't even tried to change your code like I suggested! If you would have, the test were passing. https://imgur.com/a/zcYXz3A

Comment: @akarnokd I think you should send it like an answer. I'll put a like there. It's helped me